# Extract content from web page into a variable using regex (WEB scenario step by step)

Tags: http, zabbix

I've have a problems for supervision of services using Zabbix.

So I have to make two-steps web scenario:

First: just a request to a URL. Then use regex to extract from response a HTML content (text) and put it in {myvar}. I'm using this regex `=([0-9a-z]+);`.

Then: make another request, like www.mysite.com/{myvar}. Is it possible? I saw many posts on forum.
I tried:

```
{myvar}=regex:hostid is =([0-9a-z]+);
{myvar}=regex:name="text" value="=([0-9a-z]+);
```

Also, I've a question, the |name="text"| correspond at the HTML id of the web page? Because on my first request made, my web page don't have any "id" just  and an empty header.

The error : [zabbix_server_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgtU6.png)

Comment: What is an example of the actual string you want to extract in the very first request?

Comment: only [0-9a-z] characteres. But this string start by "=" and end with ";". Like "var=nsdfs4fs6fs6fs684f4egs14gs35g;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found how to extract the string from web page using web scenario on Zabbix.

```
{myvar}=regex:[0-9]
```

then on others steps you can make request like that: www.mysite.com/{myvar}/... It's work !

Make sure your regex take the right thing !